# Why is it Ceiling() and Floor() not RoundUp() and RoundDown()

Tags: history, rounding

Most languages name the native rounding up function Ceiling() or Ceil() and the rounding down function Floor(). Yet as far as I know, this notation is pretty much never used outside of programming. Most people just refer to ceiling as "rounding up" and floor as "rounding down" so how did the ceiling/floor notation arise and become popular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the naming convention has its origin from Mathematics and Computer Science.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions